# Corpus of example sentences with context clues for dictionary words

Tags: discussion, resources

As I have found on my simple research, context clues are useful to learn meaning of dictionary words. For academic purpose, I need corpora of example sentences for dictionary words that contain such context clues as definition, contrast, example, restatement etc. It would be ok if I find 100-200 example sentences in each context clue category. Could anyone point me towards such resources?

**Update:**

If you are new to the concept of context clues, please [refer to this site](http://wps.ablongman.com/long_licklider_vocabulary_2/0,6658,416421-,00.html). For the type of sentences I am looking for, please [refer to this site](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-context-clues.html).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give a single example of what you are looking for? What do you mean by 'context clue'? Is a 'context clue' a question or a statement? Does it include the target word? What are the criteria for such a sentence?

Comment: Does the [existing answer on corpora](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2578) help here?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, from your link's page, I browsed the corpus http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/, and I feel I am near about what I am looking for, especially the wikipedia corpus provided by the site !

Comment: I'll mark this as a duplicate then. The question would be **hugely** improved by actually including a few examples rather than links. Links can die.